# Why indexof search text not correct?

Tags: c#

I am using `IndexOf` to find a character in text. My text include some special characters:

This is my code:

```
string text = "123<g>ٕ</g>";
int iPosEnd = text.IndexOf(">");
```

Result:

> iPosEnd =10

Why `IndexOf` did not find character at Position 5?

Comment: Because the 5th character is `>ٕ` and not `>`?

Comment: It looks like its a different character...special as you indicated

Comment: @CinCout, '>ٕ' is 2 characters.

Comment: In VB.net i use InStr, it search correct, but i not found InStr in C#.

Comment: "*it search correct*" - Can you prove that ?

Comment: yes,my code in vb.net: Dim iPos = InStr(text, ">"), it return 6.

Comment: `text.IndexOf(">",StringComparison.Ordinal)`

Comment: I didn't recognize that small bit down the `>ٕ`. Ignored it as some mark on my screen

Comment: Also this is likely an X/Y problem, it looks like you are trying to parse a structured language with `IndexOf` where as you might be better off using a tested dedicated parser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string.IndexOf(string)` does culture-sensitive search. This means it may *combine* characters when comparing chars. You'll find more info about string comparison in these documentation page:

- [Compare strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/comparing?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003978)
- [Best practices for comparing strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003978#specifying-string-comparisons-explicitly)
- [String comparisons are harder than it seems](https://www.meziantou.net/string-comparisons-are-harder-than-it-seems.htm)

If you want this method to return 5, you can use the `char` overload or use `StringComparison.Ordinal`

```
string text = "123<g>ٕ</g>";
int iPosEnd1 = text.IndexOf(">"); // 10
int iPosEnd2 = text.IndexOf('>'); // 5
int iPosEnd3 = text.IndexOf(">", StringComparison.Ordinal); // 5
```

Comment: Thanks, use StringComparison.Ordinal, it is ok.